# What's the source of electrons formation of inversion layer?

Tags: transistors, finfet

Until very recently I believed free electrons from the P-type substrate/body(minority charge carriers) form the inversion layer. This explanation works fine for planar MOSFET and FinFET type transistors

[image: planar MOSFET]
[image: FinFET]

But in GAA transistors(RibbonFETs and MBCFETs), the substrate isn't connected to the channel at all. What's the source of free electrons in such a device?

[image: MBCFET]

[image taken from SamsungSemiUS](https://youtu.be/3otqUu-7WUQ?si=tnNiR1c2XfirQ36v)

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add citations for where the images came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The channel region is adjacent to the **source terminal**. When the FET turns on, electrons from the source get swept into the channel (and then, after going through there, to the drain).